# Searching a substring or word in MariaDB

Tags: sql, database, full-text-search, mariadb, string-matching

I try to do full-text search on MariaDB and I encountered a problem that I cannot handle.

my table is generated as;

```
CREATE TABLE test (email TEXT, FULLTEXT(email)) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

then insert some data;

```
MariaDB [frauctive]> select * from test;
+---------------------------------+
| email                           |
+---------------------------------+
| david@hotmail.com               |
| michael@gmail.com               |
| christian@gmail.com             |
| david01@hotmail.com             |
| davidblatt@hotmail.com          |
| beckhamdavidbeckham@hotmail.com |
+---------------------------------+
```

when I use match against function, I cannot retrieve the similarity         score that I want to obtain;

```
MariaDB [frauctive]> SELECT email, MATCH(email) AGAINST('*david*' IN         BOOLEAN MODE) AS relevance 
->   FROM test ORDER BY relevance DESC;
+---------------------------------+--------------------+
| email                           | relevance          |
+---------------------------------+--------------------+
| david@hotmail.com               | 0.0906190574169159 |
| david01@hotmail.com             | 0.0906190574169159 |
| davidblatt@hotmail.com          | 0.0906190574169159 |
| michael@gmail.com               |                  0 |
| christian@gmail.com             |                  0 |
| beckhamdavidbeckham@hotmail.com |                  0 |
+---------------------------------+--------------------+
```

Altough "beckhamdavidbeckham@hotmail.com" entry contains 'david' pattern, score returns 0.

Can you please help me to fix this relevance?

Comment: The fulltext index does not work with `*david*`. You will have to use `LIKE '%david%'` which does not make use of the fulltext index.

Comment: Actually it worked. I tried 'david', 'david*', '%david%' but they didn't handle the result.

Answer (score 0):

about * wildcard :

The wildcard, indicating zero or more characters. It can only appear at the end of a word.

source:
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/fulltext-index-overview/

please try:

```
MariaDB [frauctive]> SELECT email, MATCH(email) AGAINST('david*' IN         BOOLEAN MODE) AS relevance 
->   FROM test ORDER BY relevance DESC;
```

Or

```
MariaDB [frauctive]> SELECT email, MATCH(email) AGAINST('david' IN         BOOLEAN MODE) AS relevance 
->   FROM test ORDER BY relevance DESC;
```